# how to replace specified word in vim

Tags: vim

when I search for a word
there could be many matchings
but I just want to replace some of them
so use

```
/keyword
```

and

```
n
```

I can visit each matching

is there any method to visit each matching and then decide whether to replace it or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
:%s/keyword/replacement/gc
```

Comment: why I need to  input this multiple times, sometimes, it can't get matching? not sensitive

Comment: and after I input n, the search won't continue

Comment: When I use this, "n" has the search skip to the next one, and "y" causes the current target to be replaced. If you'd like case to be ignored, add "i" to the flags. So `:s/input/output/gci`.

Comment: it seems that is only works on the words of one line, for a differnt line, I need to move the cursor to that line and input the command again

Comment: @user1769686: Oops. You're right. I forgot the `%` at the front. You can also do a visual region with this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Keep pressing <kbd>n</kbd> until you get to the first word you want to change.

Then type <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>*replacement*<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

From then on you can type <kbd>n</kbd> to skip to the next match and <kbd>.</kbd> if you want to change it (otherwise just <kbd>n</kbd> again to skip to the next one).